# Edit specific folders of application with Unisharp/Laravel-filemanager

Tags: php, laravel, unisharp-file-manager

Slider images in my application are stored in `/storage/images/slider/original/` folder. Is it possible to use Unisharp/Laravel-Filemanager to edit images in that folder ?